# Resize a popup window in testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, end-to-end

Is there a way to resize testcafe popup window? I have a test clicking on an element opens a new browser, is there a way to maximize the opened browser? `.maximizeWindow()` maximized the initial browser

Answer (score 2):

The resizing of popup windows will be available in Chrome-based browsers in v`1.10.0`. Meanwhile, you can test this functionality in the release candidate (v`1.10.0-rc.2`).